# How to use Async task with existing code

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am having difficulty trying to apply an `AsyncTask` to my existing code.

So Ill start by saying my code was working fine until I upped my target SDK, and I got the below error message:

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)`

After some research, it looks like this is because I am trying to run a network operation on the main thread which is a big no-no.  The remedy for this is to use an Asynch task to run the network operation.

Ok, makes sense to me so far, now all I have to do is implement the asynch task in my code somehow, and here lay my issue.

Basically, I have a login screen that leads to a homepage on successful login (kinda like Facebook).  When you click the login button, it sends an HTTP request to a PHP file on my server that validates the login/password and sends a response back.  Based on that response, it logs you in (or gives you an "invalid login" response").

So I am pretty sure this is the culprit.  Now, my question is, how do I run this task in a an Asynch?  I am not looking for anyone to write my code or anything, I am just looking for some guidance on how to get this started.  I have been at this for a couple days now and I am up in arms :(.

Here is the code to my login class, you can see my Asynch at the bottom:

```
public class AndroidLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    Button ok,back,exit;
    TextView result;




    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);



        // Login button clicked
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);


        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tbl_result);



    }









    public void postLoginData() {

        // Add user name and password
        EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
          String username = uname.getText().toString();

        EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        String password = pword.getText().toString();

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


        // login.php returns true if username and password match in db 
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.alkouri.com/android/login.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password  );

        try {






            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            Log.w("SENCIDE", str);

            if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
                Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE");
                result.setText("Login Successful! Please Wait...");   
            }else
            {
                Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE");
                result.setText(str);                
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
                total.append(line); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
    }

    //when register button is clicked
    public void RegisterButton(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidLogin.this, Registration.class);
        AndroidLogin.this.startActivity(myIntent);

    }







    protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
        // turns the text in the textview "Tbl_result" into a text string called "tblresult"
        TextView tblresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbl_result);
        // If "tblresult" text string matches the string "Login Successful! Please Wait..." exactly, it will switch to next activity
           if (tblresult.getText().toString().equals("Login Successful! Please Wait...")) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                //take text in the username/password text boxes and put them into an extra and push to next activity 
                 EditText uname2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
                 String username2 = uname2.getText().toString();
                 EditText pword2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
                 String password2 = pword2.getText().toString();
                 intent.putExtra("username2", username2 + "&pword=" + password2);
                 startActivity(intent);
              }    
   }













    public void onClick(View view) {

        class PostLogingDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>  
        { 
            protected Void doInBackground (Void... t)
            {
                postLoginData();
                return null;





            }



           }

                new PostLogingDataTask ().execute();
    }


}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

`Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: there is no asynctask in your code.

Comment: I just modified my code, I put the asynch task inside it @Raghunandan

Comment: updating/accessing ui from a nnackground thread is not possible. that is why you get the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       public void onClick(View view) {

    class PostLogingDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>  
    { 
        protected Void doInBackground (Void... t)
        {
            postLoginData();
        }


          protected void onPostExecute(Void v){
             // turns the text in the textview "Tbl_result" into a text string called "tblresult"
             TextView tblresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbl_result);
             // If "tblresult" text string matches the string "Login Successful! Please Wait..." exactly, it will switch to next activity
                if (tblresult.getText().toString().equals("Login Successful! Please Wait...")) {
                      Intent intent = new Intent(this, Homepage.class);
                     //take text in the username/password text boxes and put them into an extra and push to next activity 
                      EditText uname2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
                      String username2 = uname2.getText().toString();
                      EditText pword2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
                      String password2 = pword2.getText().toString();
                      intent.putExtra("username2", username2 + "&pword=" + password2);
                      startActivity(intent);
                   }    
        }
       }

            new PostLogingDataTask ().execute();
}
```

Comment: this wont work unless you put the textview's setText on back on the main thread... with `onPostExecute` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: just another comment - the onPostExecute needs to be inside the asynctask class and the return of the doInBackground needs to return the response so the post execute method can work with it.

Comment: I tried this, Eclipse asked me to add a `return null;` after the `postLoginData();` which I did.  Now I get the following error:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-04 21:10:25.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5599): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-04 21:10:25.017: E/AndroidRuntime(5599):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)`

Comment: Do not modify any UI elememts in doInBackgroundThread thread instead return a result form doInBackgroundThread about successful login. And do all the UI updates in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

Use thread to do network action and use handler to UI thread

```
new Thread(new runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("SENCIDE", str);
        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("str",str);
        msg.setData(bundle);
        handler.sendMessage(msg);   
    }
}).start();

Handler handler = new Handler() {  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {  
    super.handleMessage(msg); 
        str = msg.getData().getString("str"); 
        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE");
            result.setText("Login Successful! Please Wait...");   
        }else
        {
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE");
            result.setText(str);                
        }
    }   
};
```

Comment: What is the difference between using this or using async task?

Comment: It's not difference. But use Thread you only do network action and if you need to change UI you need use handler